# Limit the number of file descriptors a process can open over its lifespan

Tags: ubuntu, process, linux-kernel, file-descriptor, ulimit

I'm on a debian based system. One of the vulnerability I'm trying to solve is multiple `zero byte` file creation which tends to exhaust inodes available in the Filesystem.

My system allows users to execute code in a sandboxed environment and all resource ulimits are set (memory, cpu, process, STDOUT, etc). One resource limit that I'm unable to set is the total number of files a process can create.

The problem exists because there are a few world writable directories in the sandbox and file creation permissions cannot be revoked to the executing process due to other constraints.

1. ulimit has `open files (-n)` option but this only refers to number of concurrent file descriptors a process can open.
2. I tried exploring disk quota but this looks like user specific limits on number of inodes a user can create. Ideally i'd like this to be process limit rather than user limit.

Q1) Is there no reliable way to limit the number of file descriptors a process can create over its life span?

OR

Q2) Any low overhead monitoring tool to keep track of the number of `open(O_CREAT)` calls by a process?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit resources inside a process using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (which can be used with bash builtin `ulimit`).

You can set up [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) on a file system.

There is no more finegrained ways.

> Any low overhead monitoring tool to keep track of the number of open(O_CREAT) calls by a process?

You could monitor the creation of files using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities.

You might write and use some [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem for your needs.

Look also into [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization), perhaps [Docker](https://docker.com/).